# kineticjs 'on mousemove' does not track outside shapes

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a simple kineticjs program with two rectangles. One is called "rect", the other is called "grow". When the user clicks and drags in the "grow" I want to grow the other rectangle. So when I get a mousedown in grow I do a 'on mousemove' on the grow rect ( have also tried layer and stage ). This works fine except for the user moves the mouse quickly and the mouse moves outside the grow rect. I have tried putting the 'mousemove' function on the layer and the stage hoping this would allow the growing to continue even after the mouse has left the grow box but this doesn't seem to work.

The code, in it's entirety, is:

```
<html>
<body>

<br>debug:
<div id="debug">start</div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<script defer="defer">
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      });
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x : 10,
    y : 10,
    width : 90,
    height : 90,
    fill : "green"
});
var grow = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x : 80,
    y : 80,
    width : 20,
    height : 20,
    fill : "red"
});
layer.add(rect);
layer.add(grow);
layer.draw();
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();

var anchor = 0

function debug(s) {
    var div = document.getElementById("debug");
    div.innerHTML = s;
}

function doGrow() {
    debug("doGrow");
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
        var dx = mousePos.x - anchor.x;
        var dy = mousePos.y - anchor.y;
    rect.setWidth(rect.getWidth() + dx);
    rect.setHeight(rect.getHeight() + dy);
    grow.setX(grow.getX() + dx);
    grow.setY(grow.getY() + dy);
    anchor = mousePos;
    layer.draw();
}

grow.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    debug("down");
    anchor = stage.getMousePosition();
    //grow.on('mousemove', doGrow);      // These are my three attempts
    //layer.on('mousemove', doGrow);
    stage.on('mousemove', doGrow);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the deal is, it works except for the user moves too fast and the grow function doesn't continue to get called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like KineticJS will only issue a `mousemove` event if there's an element you're moving over.  So two possibilities spring to mind:

1) Add a background rectangle that covers the entire layer; you can make it transparent, I assume.

2) Attach a `mousemove` handler via other means, like jQuery, or directly in JavaScript.

You can see the second approach in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SdXqA/

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. This is my first javascript so I wouldn't have been able to figure that out for a long time. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, Charlie, I'm glad I could help!  The first solution might be more of a "Kinetic" solution, but I'm not so familiar with Kinetic, so I went for what was easy for me.